# Windows Computer won’t connect to Android Tablet via ADB

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, drivers, android

> Trying to connect an old 4.4.2 tablet via ADB (Android Debug Bridge)
>   too Windows without success.

- Only need basic access to ADB tools and fastboot.
- MTP is working, so the default driver, and cable connection are fine.
- No drivers from the manufacturer (LAZER)
- Posting here as this is more about the windows connection to the device, maybe a driver issue.
- Have tried a range of ADB packages and drivers listed on android, google and intel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Installing Minimal ADB and Fastboot in Windows**

1. Install [Google USB Drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)
2. Install [Minimal ADB and Fastboot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790)
3. Turn on ‘USB Debugging’ in Developer Options in Settings on Tablet
4. Go to Windows ‘Device Manager’
5. Go ‘Other Device’ and Right Click > Properties ‘Andriod’
6. Update Driver
   [image: Update Android Driver]
7. Browse ‘My Computer for Driver Softwear’
8. ‘Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer’
9. Select ‘Show all Devices’ click Next
10. Now wait for all devices to populate, this may take some time so be patient.
11. Select Google Inc, Andriod ADB Interface, Next, Close.
    [image: Select Google ADB Interface]
12. Andriod ADB Interface is now installed.
13. Click Start Button > Programs > Minimal ADB and Fastboot
14. A CMD window will open with something like ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>’ as its opening point
15. Now type 'adb devices'
16. Success the device should be now showing.
    [image: Command Prompt of ADB working]

Links:

- [XDA - How to use ADB (Android Debug Bridge)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2141817)
- [XDA - How to use fastboot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2277112)
- [XDA - Minimal ADB and Fastboot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790)
- [Google USB Drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)
- [Full Andriod Studio or SKD Package](https://developer.android.)